# How to move unseen windows => Cannot access my application after switching monitors

Tags: windows, window-manager

I switch monitors really often:
At work I have a very poor computer, and gpu too, which is bad at keeping its configuration, resolution and monitor position between each reboot. Both monitor are different size and resolution.

When doing that I often have applications that were on one of the monitors that remember their last position opened... so now they are unseen, at screen coordinates I cannot access.

I know there is a shortcut that can access the move functionnality of a window.
Could you remind it to me.

Do you have other trick to center all opened windows into the visible screens ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 7, with the hidden application focused use <kbd>Windows Key + Left or Right</kbd>. You will need to press the arrow key several times.

For earlier versions as well as Windows 7, press <kbd>Alt + Spacebar</kbd> to open the hidden application's system menu, then the letter <kbd>M</kbd> to select *Move*, finally <kbd>arrow key</kbd>. This will lock the window to your mouse, now move your mouse to the position you desire the window.

Comment: Good. That was exactly what I could not remember. Thx for the Windows 7 description.

Answer (score 1):

Self answer.

I kept searching for a way to do that... almost at random I clicked on the Desktop icon besides Start button... And all my wandering windows came back ;-)

So the answer is **click the desktop shortcut**. (or shortcut Windows + D).

In my search I found a nice site however that list all possible [key shortcuts for windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449). There are some I had never heard about, and that I might start using.

I found a ever more complete list of short cuts, working for windows, but I also saw some for mac. A breef look let me think it was a good link to keep. [Wikipedia lists of key shortcuts.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts)

Comment: The suggestions from the accepted answer didn't work for me, but this answer did.

Answer (score 0):

The very excellent [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) does this, amongst other multi-monitor goodies. I use it all the time.