# How to move a window to a position where the mouse pointer is at?

Tags: windows

Windows. Some programs have bugs in them that for different reasons position their windows outside of visible areas on the monitors. And then I can't access them. Then I have to either to just restart them or go to their settings in localappdata and reset the settings, so they start at their default position. Sometimes have to do a whole reinstall when I don't know where the setting is. Sometimes I don't use the second monitor and so I turn it off, and the programs still start on the second monitor and I'd like to move them to the first monitor that's enabled.

Is there a program that would move the selected window in the taskbar area to where the mouse points or to the 0,0 position on the first monitor? Or maybe someone knows a Windows API functions for this that I could use to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move unseen windows => Cannot access my application after switching monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/239891/how-to-move-unseen-windows-cannot-access-my-application-after-switching-monit)

Answer (score 2):

Try this on a visible window to see how it works:

ALT+spacebar
M
Now use the arrow keys to move the window, enter to finish.

---

Thanks go to user swwbl for this additional piece of very useful information:

> You only need to press one arrow key once, then you can use your mouse to move and left click to finish.

---

You mentioned in a comment that the windows can be waaay out of view, in which case you could use [GUIPropView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gui_prop_view.html) from NirSoft to select the window then right-click and choose "Center Selected Windows".

Comment: Been using this trick since 9x. Nice answer.

Comment: You only need to press one arrow key once, then you can use your mouse to move and left click to finish.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the answer but some programs set the window position to something like -32767 or 32767. And at the time it happens, I don't know which one is it: far away on the left or far away on the right, above or below the visible area on the monitor. So I don't know where to move. And even if I knew, it'll take a long time to actually move it to the visible area. The bug already happened yesterday in one of the programs and I couldn't move the window to the visible area. Had to restart the program.

Comment: @KulaGGin It would have been helpful to include that information in the question. Is there any chance of contacting whoever wrote the program to let them know it goes wildly wrong and please could they fix it?

Comment: @KulaGGin I've added another option in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To move the active window you can try these keyboard shortcuts:

- `Windows` + `Arrow Up` = Maximize Window
- `Windows` + `Arrow Left` = Move to the **left** side of the monitor
- `Windows` + `Arrow Right` = Move to the **right** side of the monitor